# WPF checkbox affecting multiple items in collection

Tags: wpf, binding

I am binding a nested object to a set of controls:

`Parameter.ParameterOptionGroup.ParameterOptions`

binded to:

```
<ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Parameters}">
    <ItemsControl ItemSource="{Binding ParameterOptionGroup.ParameterOption}">
        <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <CheckBox IsChecked="{Binding State}"></CheckBox>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
    </ItemsControl>
</ItemsControl>
```

Oddly, whenever I check some of the checkboxes, it triggers other checkboxes. I noticed that this happens when the checkbox's source object has the same `Id`. Truth to be told, a `ParameterOption` can be assigned as a member of any `ParameterOptionGroup`.

Is there a way to avoid this without changing my schema?

Comment: If the `Id` of the source object is the same, then it's very likely that it's looking at the same object. Perhaps you're adding the same object to the collection multiple times?

Comment: No, it's not the same object, I'm sure. 

The object is nested so `Parameters[0].ParameterOptionGroup.ParameterOption[0]` is different from `Parameters[1].ParameterOptionGroup.ParameterOption[0]`, right? Even if they have the same values.

Comment: What is `Parameters[0]` in this context? Is it an array of **classes**? How are you populating this array? Remember, classes are **reference types**, therefore if you change a value in that class, then it's changed on everything that references it. I'm fairly confident that this is the problem that I described in my previous comment.

Comment: It's a `List<Parameter>`. I am populating it from the database.  Even if that's the case, I am still confused. How can my checkboxes bounded to the same object? The number of `ParameterOption` is equal to the number of CheckBox.

Comment: What's more concerning is that your list contains duplicate objects with the same `Id`. Have you enforced the primary key constraint on the `Id` column? Perhaps you could provide a little more code to show how you are populating this list.

Comment: I would love to put the code but I think it's too complicated at this point. I am trying to narrow the scope to avoid confusing everyone else. Anyway, regarding duplicate `Id`, whenever I pull the `Parameters`, I used LINQ's `Include` method to include related records. Let me put up a screen shot. :)

Comment: Here's how I am populating the object: [link](https://www.evernote.com/l/AAS4yN8PCslFVIjpfL4QN2YA3fk2fxIM4tI). Does my `AllIncluding` extension method causes it to point to the same object?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/84350/discussion-between-jhoeforth-and-mike-eason).